# ComboBox not showing images

Tags: c#, image, xaml, combobox

I'm trying to create a comboBox with images in xaml but the images are just not showing. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong but I've followed several different tutorials and tried a lot of different things (e.g. changing how data is passed to the combobox, changing the image file format, etc...) with no success...

This is my code:

In XAML:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cbFloor" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="30" Width="120" >
                                <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                            <Image Source="{Binding Image}" Width="30" Height="30"/>
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Label}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Padding="10 0 0 0"/>
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                            </ComboBox>
```

In C#:

```
public partial class Gui : Window
{
     public Gui()
     {
          InitializeComponent();

          string imageDirectory = //string directory to a folder on my PC
          // I tried using different file formats to see if that was the problem. None of them works.
          cbFloor.Items.Add(new PictureItem(new BitmapImage(new Uri(imageDirectory + "wood.jpg", UriKind.Relative)), 
                                            "Hardwood"));
          cbFloor.Items.Add(new PictureItem(new BitmapImage(new Uri(imageDirectory + "linoleum.png", UriKind.Relative)), 
                                            "Linoleum"));
          cbFloor.Items.Add(new PictureItem(new BitmapImage(new Uri(imageDirectory + "icon16.bmp", UriKind.Relative)), 
                                            "Stone Tiles"));
     }
}


public class PictureItem
{
    public BitmapImage Image { get; set; }
    public string Label { get; set; }

    public PictureItem(BitmapImage BitImg, string label)
    {
        Image = BitImg;
        Label = label;
    }
}
```

This is what I'm getting:

[image]

I'm out of ideas... Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue will be with `UriKind.Relative`. Remove it or use `UriKind.Absolute`.

```
cbFloor.Items.Add(new PictureItem(new BitmapImage(new Uri(imageDirectory + "wood.jpg")), "Hardwood"));
cbFloor.Items.Add(new PictureItem(new BitmapImage(new Uri(imageDirectory + "linoleum.png")), "Linoleum"));
cbFloor.Items.Add(new PictureItem(new BitmapImage(new Uri(imageDirectory + "icon16.bmp")), "Stone Tiles"));
```

Or

```
cbFloor.Items.Add(new PictureItem(new BitmapImage(new Uri(imageDirectory + "OckovaciPrukaz.jpg", UriKind.Absolute)), "Hardwood"));
cbFloor.Items.Add(new PictureItem(new BitmapImage(new Uri(imageDirectory + "linoleum.png", UriKind.Absolute)), "Linoleum"));
cbFloor.Items.Add(new PictureItem(new BitmapImage(new Uri(imageDirectory + "icon16.bmp", UriKind.Absolute)), "Stone Tiles"));
```

Comment: That does solve the issue! Thank you so much for your answer! I'm pretty sure I've tried that before and it didn't work but maybe my problem was a different one then.